# How to keep a background image blurred after hover when moving to child element

Tags: css

I have a background image that blurs when hovering over the image. However when I mouse over the other div's that are on top of the background image, the blur goes away. I understand why this happens, but I am not sure if there is a simple way to fix it. I would like to keep the blur even when I move to other divs inside the parent and only have the blur removed when leaving the parent div.

```
    .image-fullbg {  
    box-sizing: border-box;     
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box;      
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

.image-fullbg:hover, 
.image-fullbg:focus {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
[parent selector]:hover .image-fullbg { -webkit-filter: blur(5px); }
```

Comment: Thank you @RamboBambo! Worked perfect!